# Reference Error: Using a For-Loop to create & send Emails from HTML Template in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-templates

**Hi,**

I'm relatively new to javascript, google apps scripts, & coding in general. I'm currently working in the Google Apps Script [g-script] environment w/ google sheets [g-sheet]. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Use a g-sheet to store a data set for accessing w/ g-script
2. Use g-script to draft & send an email using an HTML template [stored within the code editor] populated w/ the unique data located in each row.

I have a block of code that gets the data from the sheet. I then have a defined function to send the emails by using a for-loop. Within that for-loop, I am attempting to use HTMLService class to create a template from the file, populate the # of templates [in this case 3] w/ unique data from each row, & store it as a var "htmlBody". Then, use the MailApp class to send the uniquely created HTML templates.

**The error I'm receiving:**

When I run the code, I get a Reference Error that "row is not defined". I've added a picture of the Execution Log. The console.log(boatData[i]) statement is an effort trouble shoot & is the info logged to the console for the first row in the data set.

How do I fix this?

**The Code:**

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DB.charters');
  var startRow = 3 ; 
  var numRows = 3 ;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows,15);
  var boatData = dataRange.getValues();

function sendEmail() {
  for (var i in boatData) {
    var row = boatData[i] ;

    function getEmailHtml() { // gets the HTML template & makes it useable
      var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("emailTempWorkOrder.html"); // uses HtmlService class to create an HtmlTemplate object from the file in the code editor
  htmlTemplate.boats = boatData[i] ; //makes the var boatData avail within the template through the proeprty .boats
    console.log(boatData[i]); // logs the first row only
     var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent(); // converts the html file into raw binary content for HTTP responses
     return htmlBody;
    } // end of getEmailHtml()
 
  var htmlBody = getEmailHtml();
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({ // Sends the email formatted
    to: "bmsbreaux@gmail.com",
    subject: `Vessel Charter: ${row[1]} -`, // ${row[3]} [Client] [Date @ Time]
    htmlBody: htmlBody,

  }); // end of MailApp action
  } // end of for-loop
} // end of sendEmail()

// Confirmation statement.
console.log('Ran sendEmailWorkOrder(), sent emails');
```

Comment: Please put all of your var's above the function inside of the function declaration and learn how to use the builtin debugger to find what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the picture & can't after the fact:

ReferenceError: row is not defined
eval
eval
getEmailHtml @ sendEmailWorkOrder.gs:75
sendEmail @ sendEmailWorkOrder.gs:79

Comment: Like I said put the vars that you now have in global space into the function and use the debugger to single step through the function and figure out what went wrong.

Comment: You need to separate the two function declarations.  You would be well served to take a few steps back and learn javascript or atleast read a book on Javascript.

Comment: Please, when providing an error output, always indicate the line of code on which the error is occurring. The error stack trace will always tell you. With this information, you can probably debug it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code, it went well without error;
But If I were you I will make my code like this, it also works.

```
function sendEmail() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DB.charters');
  const boatData = sheet.getRange(3,1,3,15).getValues();
  let htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("emailTempWorkOrder.html").getContent();

  for (var i in boatData) {
    var row = boatData[i] ;

    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{boat}',boatData[i]);
  MailApp.sendEmail({ // Sends the email formatted
    to: "bmsbreaux@gmail.com",
    subject: `Vessel Charter: ${row[1]} -`, // ${row[3]} [Client] [Date @ Time]
    htmlBody: htmlBody,

  }); // end of MailApp action
  } // end of for-loop
} // end of sendEmail()

// Confirmation statement.
console.log('Ran sendEmailWorkOrder(), sent emails');
```

Following is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    {boat}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is sending three separate emails w/ an HTML file, but the templates are not populating w/ each row's unique data. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not quite understand your question.  Each time forloop running, the {} will be replaced with boatData[i].